# Doing data validation after saving the object in a atomic transaction. Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

The current flow I use is this:

```
# Here there is a long and complicated verification to check that the submitted data is valid,
# involving lots of calculations and queries.

with transaction.atomic():
    # save the submitted data
```

But instead I could do

```
def saved_data_is_valid():
    # some short and simple calculations.

...


# skip the validation before saving data.
with transaction.atomic():
    # save the submitted data in the database without commiting it.
    if not saved_data_is_valid():
        raise Exception("Some exception so the transaction will roll back")
```

I wonder what the performance hit for the database will be with all the dead rows this will create, considering that `AUTOVACUUM` is `ON`, and `default_transaction_isolation` is `read committed`.

Also considering that the submitted data is in most cases valid.

Comment: Sounds like a clever idea to decouple validation from upload - you can do both in parallel, then `rollback` the insert if data validation result comes back negative. Performance depends on your indexes that'll have to be rebuilt, the fillfactor of the table and indexes, the size and frequency of the uploads, whether you `cluster` the table by an index. You can partition the target table (batch numbers? timestamps?), upload to a separate table and either drop it or attach as partition to the main table, based on validation result - this won't affect earlier partitions and their indexes.

Comment: You are essentially incurring the cost of validating the data for every insertion. What benefit do you expect to get from this approach?

Comment: Validating the data after the insert is much easier in my case because I do not only insert data, but also modify data in other tables. So validating before would mean that I had to do a "simulation" of the whole process (which involves many other queries and aggregations) without persisting anything. Then this idea came to my mind knowing it would be a lot simpler if I just "save" the data in a transaction, but not commit it, then do the validation and if the validation fails, I just roll back. But I'm not sure if this is a sane approach so that's why I asked here.